# Creating a resuable template in Django

Tags: python, django, templates

**Question 1:**

So I'm working on a template for an email in Django. My email has a table in it, and I need to put formatting into each row of the table because some email clients require all CSS styles to be inline.  So I created a template to implement the table row, and I'm calling it with `with` for each row.

Row template

```
<tr style="blahblah">
   <td>{{ description}}</td>
   <td>{{ value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Then I'm able to call the template like this

```
{% include 'included_template.html description=some_context_var value=some_other_var %}
```

All is right with the world, until I need something other than a context variable to go in one of the table cells.  In my case, I need to reformat a DateTimeField in date format like so:

```
{{ create_date| date:"N j, Y" }}
```

The above works fine, but when I do:

```
 {% include "included_template.html" with description="Date:" value=create_date| date:"N j, Y"  %}
```

I get an error:

```
django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '|' from 'invoice.create_date|'
```

**Question 2:**

I also have cases where I want to compose multiple values into one of the cells, e.g.:

```
Hi {{first_name}} {{last_name}}
```

Is there any way I can yield back to the parent template to render a body, or compose the variables I need within the template to pass to the included template?  I can add all this stuff to the context but it doesn't sit well with me, especially since the date format function I need doesn't seem to be available on the python side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

Although this works:

```
{{ create_date| date:"N j, Y" }}
```

It should actually be this (Note that the space has been removed before `date`):

```
{{ create_date|date:"N j, Y" }}
```

With that change, the following should now work:

```
 {% include "included_template.html" with description="Date:" value=create_date|date:"N j, Y"  %}
```

**Question 2:**

You can use Django's [built-in template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#add)

```
{% with full_name=first_name|add:" "|add:last_name %}
    Hi {{ full_name }}
{% endwith %}
```

One warning: if you use `add` on two numbers, you will get the sum, not a concatenation.